# Upgrade from 18.04.1 (bionic) to 18.10 (cosmic) fails

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, update-manager, do-release-upgrade, 18.10

I tried to upgrade using software updater but upgrade window silently closed after downloading the files. Then I tried upgrading with `do-release-upgrade` but that also failed without an obvious error message.

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                                                                      
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,263 kB]                                                                                             
Fetched 1,264 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                            
authenticate 'cosmic.tar.gz' against 'cosmic.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'cosmic.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                  
Hit http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                          
Hit http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                           
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                 
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

There are no error messages in syslog, and in `/var/log/dist-upgrade` There're no error lines:

```
2018-11-04 18:47:51,846 INFO Using config files '['./DistUpgrade.cfg']'
2018-11-04 18:47:51,846 INFO uname information: 'Linux white 4.15.0-38-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 10 10:59:38 UTC 2018 x86_64'
2018-11-04 18:47:52,185 INFO apt version: '1.6.6'
2018-11-04 18:47:52,185 INFO python version: '3.6.6 (default, Sep 12 2018, 18:26:19) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]]'
2018-11-04 18:47:52,188 INFO release-upgrader version '18.10.11' started
2018-11-04 18:47:52,198 INFO locale: 'en_US' 'UTF-8'
2018-11-04 18:47:52,246 INFO screen could not be run
2018-11-04 18:47:52,366 DEBUG Using 'DistUpgradeViewText' view
2018-11-04 18:47:52,412 DEBUG enable dpkg --force-overwrite
2018-11-04 18:47:52,445 DEBUG creating statefile: '/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt-clone_system_state.tar.gz'
2018-11-04 18:47:55,863 DEBUG lsb-release: 'bionic'
2018-11-04 18:47:55,864 DEBUG _pythonSymlinkCheck run
2018-11-04 18:47:55,865 DEBUG openCache()
2018-11-04 18:47:55,865 DEBUG No such plugin directory: ./plugins
2018-11-04 18:47:55,865 DEBUG plugins for condition 'PreCacheOpen' are '[]'
2018-11-04 18:47:55,865 DEBUG plugins for condition 'cosmicPreCacheOpen' are '[]'
2018-11-04 18:47:55,865 DEBUG plugins for condition 'from_bionicPreCacheOpen' are '[]'
2018-11-04 18:47:55,865 DEBUG quirks: running PreCacheOpen
2018-11-04 18:47:55,865 DEBUG running Quirks.PreCacheOpen
2018-11-04 18:47:56,403 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 91315
2018-11-04 18:47:56,403 DEBUG need_server_mode(): run in 'desktop' mode, (because of pkg 'ubuntu-desktop')
2018-11-04 18:47:56,403 DEBUG checkViewDepends()
2018-11-04 18:47:56,404 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=False)
2018-11-04 18:47:58,472 DEBUG openCache()
2018-11-04 18:47:59,005 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 91315
2018-11-04 18:47:59,005 DEBUG doPostInitialUpdate
2018-11-04 18:47:59,005 DEBUG plugins for condition 'PostInitialUpdate' are '[]'
2018-11-04 18:47:59,005 DEBUG plugins for condition 'cosmicPostInitialUpdate' are '[]'
2018-11-04 18:47:59,005 DEBUG plugins for condition 'from_bionicPostInitialUpdate' are '[]'
2018-11-04 18:47:59,005 DEBUG quirks: running cosmicPostInitialUpdate
2018-11-04 18:47:59,005 DEBUG running Quirks.cosmicPostInitialUpdate
2018-11-04 18:47:59,027 DEBUG abort called
2018-11-04 18:47:59,027 DEBUG openCache()
2018-11-04 18:47:59,554 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 91315
```

I installed all updates and restarted before trying to upgrade. Anything else I should check?

Answer (score 0):

How are you on space?
As far as I've seen, 18.10 is a failure of an OS update in and of itself.  The kernel has more panics than a house full of drug dealers with lights flashing through their front windows.  Best suggestion is to stick with what you have for now.  Otherwise, run a check for broken packages and verify that they are, in fact, all working and matching dependencies.
There should be an error that it gives you if the upgrade failed.  If it's just hanging after reboot, the only way that I've found for it to continue loading is by changing to another session via alt-ctrl-f2 and then back with alt-ctrl-f1 to unhang a wait to load.